# Open link in a new window with Capybara

Tags: capybara

In Capybara, is it possible to open a link in a new window, rather than the current one?

Comment: Yes, you can use javascript to do that with window.open.
See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056763/how-do-i-open-a-new-window-in-capybara-with-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Should it be a new window or a new tab? For the second variant see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this element is a link you can just get its href and open it in a new window:

```
url = find('.some_link')[:href]
within_window open_new_window do
  # do something
end
```

`open_new_window` has been added in Capybara 2.3