# How do I open a new window in Capybara with Selenium webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I found a code: `page.driver.browser.switch_to.window`, which is apparently switching to already opened window. How do we open a new window using page.driver.browser object?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using JavaScript to do this:

```
When /^I open a new window for "([^"]*)"$/ do |url|
str =
<<END_TAG
     window.open("#{url}", "window_name", "height=800,width=1000");
END_TAG
  page.execute_script(str)
end
```

Answer (score 9):

I ended up here, even if is a old thread, might be useful for someone, you can create and use windows like this:

```
new_window = open_new_window
switch_to_window new_window
```

or:

```
within_window new_window do
end
```

you can also find new windows through windows object.

```
open_new_window
new_window = windows.last
```

References:

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Session:open_new_window

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FSession%3Aswitch_to_window

https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#working-with-windows

[With Capybara, how do I switch to the new window for links with "_blank" targets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612038/with-capybara-how-do-i-switch-to-the-new-window-for-links-with-blank-targets)

Comment: This should be the correct answer! it works and is simpler.